# Was Charlie Weasley a prefect too?

Tags: harry-potter

**Chapter 9, HP and the Order of the Phoenix**

> Mrs. Weasley says that everyone in the family has been a *Prefect*,
>   but Charlie was a Quidditch Captain.
>
> In the sixth book, (The Half Blood Prince) Hermione detailed in here
>   that **Prefects have the same or equal status with Quidditch Captains.**

Ron was also some kind of jealous because his brothers were Prefect and his brother Charlie was a Quidditch Captain.

Mrs. Weasley clearly said that everyone has been a prefect, but Charlie was a Quidditch Captain. Was Charlie an exception for what Mrs. Weasley said? But Hermione says that they just have an equal status. If that is so, **Did Charlie become a Prefect?**

Comment: *Mrs Weasley let out a shriek just like Hermione’s. ‘I don’t believe it! I don’t believe it! Oh, Ron, how wonderful! A prefect! That’s everyone in the family!’* OOTP

Comment: He was a prefect *and* Quidditch captain

Comment: This is actually a really good question, because every result from Google seems to just state that Charlie was a prefect as though it were concrete, unquestionable fact, and every single one just puts the entire OOTP book as the reference for that statement. I'm interested to see that actually, he may have just been a Quidditch Captain and nothing else.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I think the same thing too. There is no straight phrase that described Charlie as a prefect. I wonder if he obtained those 2 positions within his time in Hogwarts.

Comment: He may well have done, but to be honest I think your best bet would genuinely be to tweet JK. She might just answer you and we'll have _word of God_ as to whether or not Charlie was also a Prefect or just Captain.

Comment: Maybe. After all she is the one who knew every details that are not included in the book.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Agreed with your comment about "every result from Google" matter of factly asserting his prefectship with this one Molly quote. I, however, find that George's need to protest about their exclusion to her "whole family" line, without Fred adding "Yeah, and Charlie wasn't a prefect either" or something along these lines to serve as evidence *for* rather than *against*. I, too, think a tweet to Rowling is the way to go.

Comment: @Ghoti and Chips Absolutely. It is time that we personally seek the answer from Rowling since the books haven't detailed yet what happened during every scenarion that wasn't incuded. Way to go

Comment: I don't know if that's sarcasm or not. Anyway, Charlie *was* a prefect, as I detailed in my answer below. If you need an explicit "Yes, Charlie was a prefect", you'll have to consult Rowling.

Comment: A great question, and much better than your prior one. Keep them coming and you'll do fine!

Comment: I guess so. My first question was really a blur. I guess I based 'em too much with movies. Thanks Valorum!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Yes, Charlie Weasley was a prefect

In the Weasley family, **four of the children** became prefects, at the time of *Order of the Phoenix*.

> “Drawing room . . .” he growled, as the pupil contracted. “Desk in
>   the corner? Yeah, I see it. . . . Yeah, it’s a boggart. . . . Want me to go
>   up and get rid of it, Molly?”
>   “No, no, I’ll do it myself later,” beamed Mrs. Weasley. “You have
>   your drink. We’re having a little bit of a celebration, actually. . . .” She
>   gestured at the scarlet banner. “**Fourth prefect in the family**!” she said
>   fondly, ruffling Ron’s hair.
>   <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter 9</sub></sup>

1. Bill Weasley
2. Charlie Weasley
3. Percy Weasley
4. Ron Weasley

It is fair to call into question Molly's initial "That's everyone in the family" line, but Note that nobody protests this number (she corrected herself from "everyone in the family [6 sons, 1 daughter]", to **4**), nor do Fred and George protest by noting "Charlie *wasn't* a prefect", despite protesting about themselves not being included in the "whole family" claim from Molly in your question.

Also, there is this letter from Percy Weasley

> *Dear Ron,
>
>   I have only just heard (from no less a person than the Minister
>   of Magic himself, who has it from your new teacher, Professor
>   Umbridge) that you have become a Hogwarts prefect.
>
>   I was most pleasantly surprised when I heard this news and
>   must firstly offer my congratulations. I must admit that **I have always
>   been afraid that you would take what we might call the
>   “Fred and George” route**, rather than following in my footsteps, so
>   you can imagine my feelings on hearing you have stopped flouting
>   authority and have decided to shoulder some real responsibility.*

This further emphasizes that Fred and George were the odd ones out.

Comment: @Skooba And now?

Comment: up vote all around

Comment: Yes, you've got a point about Fred and George being forgotten. If that is so, we may consider that Charlie was one of the four prefects, if we're going to rely with Molly's statement.

Comment: @BookStriker It's not only her statement, it's people's reactions to her statement (being corrected when she excludes Fred and George from the "whole family" line, and nobody making a point about Charlie *not* being a prefect later on during the celebration when she says "fourth prefect"). This makes much more sense than the alternative answer, which uses logic/quotes which I have counter-argued in the comments.

Comment: Having said that, I think you've really got a point about the arguments I read recently pointing about Charlie, Bill, Percy, and Ron.

Comment: This seems pretty categorical. This can't really be interpreted any other way,  except at a stretch.

Comment: Fourth perfect in the family? Perhaps Arthur was one.

Comment: @SQB If one assumes she is referring to their whole family, the number would probably be higher than four, considering their (pure-blood) heritage goes back many generations. Meanwhile, the interpretation I present in my answer seems much more logically feasible.

Comment: "Heavily Implied" is not the same as proof. "At a stretch" is still possible, even if unlikely. We don't even know whether or not a Qudditch Captain can also be a prefect in the first place. What if a Quidditch Captain cannot be considered for a Prefect position, and vice versa? There are too many things we don't know to say anything with certainty. That being said, this is still obviously the best answer we're going to get, short of JK answering the question herself.

Comment: I just don't feel like this answer should say "Yes, Charlie was a prefect" as though there's no other possible option. "Yes, Charlie was most likely a prefect", I would be ok with, because it accepts that while that is the most likely scenario, other potential scenarios do exist, depending on interpretation.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo  *Yes, yes, yes, yes, and what if the core is made of cheese?* —  Dr. Conrad Zimsky

Comment: Well, I think there still lies the posibility that a Captain could also be the one to step up to the position of the prefect. I mean, there is still a huge difference with these positions.

Answer (score 17):

### The statement in question also disregards Fred and George.

> ‘I don’t believe it! I don’t believe it! Oh, Ron, how wonderful!
>   A prefect! **That’s everyone in the family!’**
>
> **‘What are Fred and I, next-door neighbours?’ said George indignantly**, as his mother pushed him aside and flung her arms around
>   her youngest son.

From the outset we must not take this line literally since she forgot Fred and George who are sitting right next to her.

The books only ever mention that Charlie was Quidditch captain outright

> You could say I’ve got a
>   lot to live up to. Bill and Charlie have already left – Bill was Head
>   Boy and Charlie was captain of Quidditch. Now Percy’s a Prefect.

### Edit: Its still unclear Charlie was a prefect, just implied.

As Ghoti has found later in the chapter she does specifically say Ron is the 4th prefect.

> We’re having a little bit of a celebration, actually ...’
>   She gestured at the scarlet banner. ‘Fourth prefect in the family!’
>   she said fondly, ruffling Ron’s hair.

This quote implies that Charlie is also was a prefect since George and Fred clearly were not. However, even here it doesn't spell it out that Charlie was a prefect, and so you could still say that she could be including herself or Mr. Weasly as one of the four, however, it does strongly imply that she means her children in this instance.

When Harry is made quidditch captain

> ‘That gives you equal status with prefects!’ cried Hermione happily.
>   ‘You can use our special bathroom now, and every- thing!’
>
> ‘Wow, I remember when Charlie wore one of these,’ said Ron,

While less likely now, she could still simply mean that 4 of her children achieved the "status" of a prefect.

Comment: 1. Nobody in the room points out to Molly, "Charlie wasn't a prefect" after George protests about his and Fred's exclusion from the "whole family" claim. 2. Molly doesn't say "Bill was a Prefect" either in that second quote, yet we don't assume he wasn't a Prefect, he simply assume she is listing off their most impressive titles (in the case of Charlie, Quidditch Captain > Prefect). I don't think "*all evidence points to Charlie **only** being Quidditch captain*", certainly the quotes you provide aren't convincing.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to make an edit that changes the **entire meaning** of your answer. You went from "Evidence points to **only** being a Quidditch captain" to agreeing with me that he probably indeed was a prefect, after I went and fetched the correct quotes. I think the Edit is even less justified when I included all the info in an answer of my own.

Comment: @GhotiandChips 1. i can edit my question in anyway i want, and 2 i still state that it doesnt prove he is a prefect.

Comment: I think you'll find that you actually *can't* "edit [your] question in anyway [you] want". Consult the [edit help section](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing), you will find *"clarify the meaning of the post (without **changing that meaning**)"* as one of the guidelines.

Comment: @Ghoti: That's talking about edits to *somebody else's* answer, not your own answer.

Comment: @Kevin True that, plus the edits are publicly visible, people can see how much (if at all) Himarm's stance changed through editing after I contributed my answer.

Comment: @GhotiandChips There's never been a problem with editing your answer in major ways.  Adding new information and editing answers is how we can stay up-to-date and accurate.  After all, if a new canon source comes out, it would be a shame to not be able to change an answer to reflect new details.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Yes, I inferred as much after Kevin's response, thank you, though, for adding another logical reasoning behind it :) Makes sense, I just saw the aforementioned "without changing meaning" guideline over and over again, and (falsely) presumed it applied to *all* edits. Happy to be wrong here.